# SolrNet multiple connection with one core and type

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

Hello i have a very big problem. I need to take/create connection to one core with single type and make any operations.
For now its looks like:

```
public class SolrMachine<T> : ISolrMachine<T> where T : ISolrRecord
{

    private ISolrOperations<T> actuallyInstance { get; set; }

    public SolrMachine(string coreName)
    {
        string url = String.Format("http://xxxx/solr/{0}", coreName);
        ISolrConnection solrConnection = new SolrConnection(url) { HttpWebRequestFactory = new SolrAuthWebRequestFactory()};
        Startup.Init<T>(solrConnection);
        var myInstance = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<T>>();
        this.actuallyInstance = myInstance;
    }
}
```

`ISolrMachine<T>` is a interface with my methods to operate on solr core. `ISolrRecord` is a interface with properties in my cores.

Now, when I am doing a connection with two other cores all works perfectly.

```
SolrMachine<SolrTypeOne> firstCoreConnection = new SolrMachine<SolrTypeOne>(firstCoreName);
SolrMachine<SolrTypeTwo> secondCoreConnection = new SolrMachine<SolrTypeTwo>(secondCoreName);
// operation on firstCoreConnection and secondCoreConnection works
```

But when I'm trying to connect with one type and one coreName i have exception on `Startup.Init<T>(solrConnection)`. I know that `Startup` container blocks a connection with same `Type` and `coreName` but always I am creating a new instance to this SolrMachine. I expect this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public MyMethod()
    {
        SolrMachine<SolrTypeOne> myConn = new SolrMachine<SolrTypeOne>(firstCoreName);
        // operation
    }
}

class SecondSomeClass
{
    public MyMethod()
    {
        SolrMachine<SolrTypeOne> myConn2 = new SolrMachine<SolrTypeOne>(firstCoreName);
        // here it's not work
    }
}
```

How to avoid this ?

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Multi-core-instance.md

Comment: There is answer for my case? :)

Comment: "The built-in container is currently limited to access multiple cores/instances with different mapped types."

Comment: Yes I know and i said that earlier. Now I am trying with structure map and windsor facility. In structuremap i've got error: `Cannot initialize type 'StructureMap.SolrNetIntegration.Config.SolrServers' with a collection initializer because it does not implement`

Comment: Can you post that StructureMap error in https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, problem was that my Solr using a `IHttpWebRequestFactory`. From SolrNet multicore documentation author doesn't take this problem. Here is my solution (use Windsor):

```
public class SolrAuth : IHttpWebRequestFactory
{
    public IHttpWebRequest Create(Uri url)
    {
        //... credentials, timeouts, etc.
        return new HttpWebRequestAdapter((HttpWebRequest)webrequest);
    }
}
public class SolrMachine<T> : ISolrMachine<T> where T : ISolrRecord
{
    public WindsorContainer myContainer = new WindsorContainer();
    private ISolrOperations<T> actuallyInstance { get; set; }
    public SolrMachine(string coreName)
    {
        var url = string.Format("http://xxx/solr/{0}", coreName);
        myContainer.Register(Component.For<IHttpWebRequestFactory>().ImplementedBy<SolrAuth>());
        var solrFacility = new SolrNetFacility(string.Format("http://xxx/solr/{0}", "defaultCollection"));
        solrFacility.AddCore(coreName, typeof(T), url);
        myContainer.AddFacility(solrFacility);
        this.actuallyInstance = myContainer.Resolve<ISolrOperations<T>>();
    }
}
```